# How can I drop and recreate all dependencies (keys, constraints, and views) for altering columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to alter all `varchar` columns in my database to `nvarchar`, using a T-SQL script.

There are a lot of dependencies (keys, constraints, and views) that cause problems when trying to alter.

> The object 'X' is dependent on column 'Y'. ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN 'Y' failed because one or more objects access this column.

My unsuccessful attempts: forcing a change with PowerShell, and creating a generate script for the whole database and using that to create a copy with all the changes I need. These attempts didn't work, because I lost the table data and the generate scripts were too big for any program to handle.

How does one create all `DROP` and `CREATE` scripts of the objects that cause problems when trying to alter to make the changes and recreate the database schema like it was before altering?

Comment: My goal is to have a T-SQL solution to alter database columns. That includes finding, dropping and recreating dependencies. I found a few ways to do this, for example powershell or cmd commands aswell as working with database generate scripts. The Problem is that you need to have certain programms or apps installed to do those things, like ssdt. I tried creating a generic T-SQL script. I can't get it to work though because I just lack the experience of creating such a big script to puzzle together all the create scripts. And here I am asking people who are way better then me.

Comment: Multi-step process. Drop all procedures and functions. Drop all views, Drop triggers, Drop FKs. Drop Primary keys and all other constraints. Make your changes. Then recreate them in the reverse order. That is work you will need to do but scripts likely can be found that do much of this. The SSMS scripting tool can do much of this as well though you will still need to assemble the bits you need. Unfortunately you have a task that is very complicated and requires more skill than you possess

Comment: the comment above pretty much summarize all what you have to do for this change. My advice : let it down. Its not worth it. I dont see why such a column type change would be absolutely necessary at whole database level. If you need this data in other format, just make a computed column out of it, or CAST it in your SELECT statements.

Comment: How big is "the generate scripts were too big for any program to handle"? More than 42 YiB?

Comment: The final goal is to support unicode in our database, which isn't possible without altering those columns. Also the generate scripts (that include table data, so nothing gets deleted) are about 1 million lines. They make SSMS or azure data studio crash when opening or when trying to execute.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415924/problems-with-the-stack-overflow-guidelines).